# SP Foundation 2013: Cannot Restore File From Site Collection Recycle Bin

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

On SharePoint Foundation 2013, I am receiving an error when attempting to restore a file to a document library from the Site Collection Recycle Bin (AdminRecycleBin.aspx). I navigate to the Recycle Bin page, check the box next to the file I would like to restore, then click "Restore Selection". I get a pop-up window asking if I'm sure I would like to restore the file and upon clicking yes, I get a "Sorry, something went wrong" error that simply states an error occurred and gives me a Correlation ID to use in searching log files.

I have received this error on each one of the two dozen or so documents I tested that are currently in the Site Collection Recycle Bin as well as for the handful of documents I created in a document library and promptly deleted to test whether new documents are also affected. I tried a number of things that came up in a Google search for this error with no success:

- The drive hosting the content db has plenty of space
- SQL Server does not have a size limit set for the content db
- There are no quotas set in Central Administration
- There is no document in the library with the same name

Does anyone know why I might be encountering this issue and what might resolve it? I have included all messaging from the log file related to this issue below (I formatted it to make it more readable and omitted the first few columns of the log). Thanks in advance!

---

```
    Name=Request (POST:http://sitecollection:80/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx)   64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|<myuserid>, ClaimsCount=54   64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    Site=/  64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask,Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion,String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes,Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState,String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)
         at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
         at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
         at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
         at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
         at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()
         at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
         at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
         at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
         at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
         at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
         at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
         at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
         at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    Spent 0 ms to bind 29783 byte file stream   64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 03/04/2014 16:14:19.66, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.033790062342665    64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean retryfordeadlock)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean retryfordeadlock)  ClientConnectionId:4d7818bf-ca8e-4e4e-8b96-79d0a58b6857    64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    ExecuteQuery failed with original error 0x80131904  64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    Failed to get output parameter, HR: 0x80131509, Native stack:   64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80131904  64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    SPRequest.GetAdminRecycleBinItems: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-2046319126-465335469-1849977318-11042, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrSiteUrl=http://sitecollection    64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904, StackTrace:
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.EnsureContent()
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.get_Count()
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.FindRowIndex(Guid id)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.GetSortedIds(Guid[] ids, SPRecycleBinItemType[]& itemTypes)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.RecycleBinPage.ProcessAction(String action, String guidString)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.RecycleBinPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
         at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
         at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
         at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
         at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
         at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
         at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
         at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
         at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    Application error when access /_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx, Error=Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904   
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetAdminRecycleBinItems(String bstrSiteUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetAdminRecycleBinItems(String bstrSiteUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems) 64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 03/04/2014 16:14:19.74, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0491491815893309   64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean retryfordeadlock)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean retryfordeadlock)  ClientConnectionId:4d7818bf-ca8e-4e4e-8b96-79d0a58b6857    64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    ExecuteQuery failed with original error 0x80131904  64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    Failed to get output parameter, HR: 0x80131509, Native stack:   64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80131904  64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    SPRequest.GetAdminRecycleBinItems: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-2046319126-465335469-1849977318-11042, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrSiteUrl=http://sitecollection    64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904, StackTrace:
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.EnsureContent()
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.get_Count()
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.FindRowIndex(Guid id)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.GetSortedIds(Guid[] ids, SPRecycleBinItemType[]& itemTypes)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.RecycleBinPage.ProcessAction(String action, String guidString)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.RecycleBinPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
         at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
         at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
         at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
         at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.ErrorAppHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)
         at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()
         at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
         at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
         at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
         at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
         at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
         at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904    
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetAdminRecycleBinItems(String bstrSiteUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetAdminRecycleBinItems(String bstrSiteUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems) 64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    Getting Error Message for Exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80131904): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904     
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetAdminRecycleBinItems(String bstrSiteUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems)
         at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetAdminRecycleBinItems(String bstrSiteUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems) 64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    MDSLog: An error page was detected by MDS: Context Page MP (currentMPToken) = ['|:|_LAYOUTS|15|ERRORV15.MASTER:0.15.0.0.0.15.0.4420.1017.0.FALSE.:en-US:en-US:RW'], MP supplied by page in URL (originalMPToken) = ['|:|_CATALOGS|MASTERPAGE|SEATTLE.MASTER:3.15.0.0.0.15.0.4420.1017.0.FALSE.:en-US:en-US:RW'], Current Request URL = ['http://sitecollection/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx']   64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
    Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://sitecollection:80/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx)). Execution Time=206.193872018603 64157a9c-4a0e-a085-4388-068b6527e47b
```

Comment: Does it happen with the Site Recycle Bin as well? Are it regular documents or 'special' files like master pages ? Do you have Remote Blob Storage enabled?

Comment: I am unable to restore a file from the Site Recycle Bin on any of the 3 sites I tested. One thing I noticed in this test was that after deleting a file from the document library, the site recycle bin displayed it twice despite saying there was only 1 item. The document I originally tried to restore is a MS Word document. I also should add that since this instance of SPF 2013 was installed ~8 months ago, the Site Collection Recycle Bin has worked flawlessly until now. Prior to this week, I last used it ~3 weeks ago to restore a couple of files and it worked perfectly at that time.

Comment: I didn't realize comments couldn't have carriage returns, so I ended up submitting the above comment prematurely without an answer to your RBS question. RBS is **not** enabled on our instance of SPF 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the Site Collection to a new Content Database (Move-SPSite) just to rule out a DB schema issue with the current DB. This is really a wild guess based on the SQL related error you're receiving, but it could be way off.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Should we be enabling RBS as a part of this move (or even just in general)?

Comment: RBS serves a specific need and causes additional maintenance so I wouldn't advise it as a default.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been reported elsewhere:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4a7825fa-7dc5-43d9-9a4c-dd29dbd41cb0/cant-restore-document-from-site-collection-recycle-bin?forum=sharepointgeneral

Is the site currently being evaluated for upgrade? If so, you may want to try removing the evaluation site collection.